# Flutter: Customising focused input text border colour

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been attempting to customize the color of the border of the focused input text field.

```dart
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
        helperText: 'Helper Text',
        counterText: '0 characters',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    )
```

So basically, if I click on the input box, it will simply turn the border blue, but I would like to customize this color to green. I'm really not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: there is an attribute: focusedBorder

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using focusedBorder

```
  TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
          hintText: 'Hint Text',
          helperText: 'Helper Text',
          counterText: '0 characters',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
```

Your result -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use following properties to customize Text Field :

```
enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
             borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.4),
           ),
           disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
             borderSide: BorderSide.none,
           ),
           focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
             borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.2),
           ),
```